# Only blows hot air on both modes

Tags: thermostat

I just installed a new Honeywell WiFi thermostat and my heat pump only blows hot air on heat and cool mode.

Comment: Are we to assume that it blew cold air before you installed the new thermostat? Would you care to show us a pic of what you did with the wiring? [Edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/165856/edit) your question to add some detail.

Comment: Double check your wiring, you have to of mixed something up